# Default descontructed parameter on function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to use a function that works for two scenarios, it can either iterate through the key of an object in array or the array value itself. So this prints fine:

```
const arr1 = [{
  car: 'audi'
},{
  car: 'bmw'
}]

const printCars = arr1.map(({ car }) => console.log(car))
// audi
// bmw
```

But I dont know how to use the same function's default parameter to allow for a simple array

```
const arr2 = ['audi', 'bmw'];

const printCars = arr2.map(({ car }) => console.log(car));
// Obviously car is undefined
```

I wonder how can I do something like

```
const arr = ['audi', 'bmw'];
const printCars = arr.map(({ car } = car) => console.log(car));
// audi
// bmw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to do this in just the parameter list. You can destructure on the first line of the function, and assign a default value of the whole item:

```js
const arr2 = ['audi', 'bmw'];

arr2.forEach((item) => {
  const { car = item } = item;
  console.log(car);
});
```

Note that since you aren't creating a new array, but performing *side-effects* (`console.log`), you should not use `.map` - instead, use `forEach`. `.map` is only for when you need to transform every element of one array into a new element in a different returned array.

It would be *possible* to put the proper value into the `car` variable using just the parameter list, but it's quite ugly and an abuse of default arguments, I'll put it below for informational purposes only (please don't use it):

```js
const arr2 = ['audi', 'bmw'];

arr2.forEach((item, i, arr, { car = item } = item) => console.log(car));
```

The above works because `forEach` only takes 3 arguments, so the 4th will be `undefined`, so you can use default arguments to put something into the `car` identifier conditionally.

Comment: Yeah I know, I am actually using reduce on the real function, this was an example, but you are right.

Comment: Thanks, that works great, I will declare the variable on the body.